# How to change xfce4.8 windows buttons horizontal size?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, xfce-panel

In my opinion, Xfce buttons size a bit too big. Where i can change it ?

Provided gtk tool doesn't have that option and i think everythink are in some configuration file, but don't now where is it.

Image:
[image: Windows buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button size is dynamic and they reduce their size alone while the bar is filling. If you want you can insert a separator on each side of the application buttons bar and with the global size reduced the button size will be reduced.

Comment: Ahh, totally forgotten about dynamic size... Anyway, thanks.